# jQuery plugin to apply also on dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a jquery plugin that should handle extra information on links to specify open behavior.

For example, I want to supports markup like :

1. `<a href="somewhere" data-openmode="NewWindow" class="openmode" />`
2. `<a href="somewhere" data-openmode="Modal" class="openmode" />`
3. `<a href="somewhere" class="openmode" /> <!-- Not specified -->`

The first should open in a new window, the second in a modal dialog, the third should open with the native behavior (whatever target has been set on the tag).

I would like to create a plugin for this behavior as generic as possible. I've written by now:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myOpenMode = function () {
        return this.mousedown(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            var mode = $this.data("openmode");
            var href = this.href;
            var handled = true;
            if (mode) {
                switch (mode) {
                    case "NewWindow":
                    case "1":
                        window.open(href, "_blank");
                        break;
                    case "Dialog":
                    case "2":
                        openAsDialog(href);
                        break;

                    // Actually, there are other options, but I removed them for clarity

                    default:
                        handled = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                handled = false;
            }
            return !handled;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This code allows me to call from any page something like:

```
$(function(){
    $(".openmode").myOpenMode();
});
```

This is working for statically generated tags. However, my applications may generate markup dynamically (most of time using jsRender, but this does not matters).

But because this behavior is set up once when the javascript file is loaded, it won't take dynamically generated objects.

What should I do to handle my requirement?

1. I tried to use the `on` method to monitor load events, but this does not works :

   ```
   $(function(){
       $(document).on("load",".openmode", function() { $(this).myOpenMode(); });
   });
   ```

   I understand this does not works because the "load" event does not bubbles
2. I was thinking about modifying my plugin to put the "on" inside the plugin, but I don't like this idea because it introduces some out of scope behavior in the plugin
3. I can also call the plugin each time a dynamic node is created, but it will also introduce dependencies into other parts. My plugin won't be as autonomous as I would like.

Does anyone has a suggestion to handle my requirement, keeping my plugin as isolated as possible?

**[edit]** This should works with IE8 and later (and ideally with other browsers)

**[edit]** here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevebeauge/7cqXC/) that illustrate the issue (just click on `Add` and try to click on the newly created element).

Comment: .on() is for event handlers, not plugin. You have to call the plugin each time a dynamic node is created or using observers to check when a new specific element (.openmode) is added to DOM and code your logic according to this. Of course, observers can get some performance issue.

Comment: inside plugin you are not using .on().

Comment: @roasted: I'm not fan of using `on()` within the plugin. However, as far as I understand my google searchs, observers does not exists with IE, and are performance killer.

Comment: not a nice implementation IMHO - you should not be trapping the `mousedown` event, but instead the `click` event.   This code will fail if keyboard navigation is used to visit the links.

Comment: @Alnitak: you are right, I'll change this in my actual code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plugins added to `$.fn` should only apply to the listed elements, and not any future elements.

You should concentrate on having your plugin provide the *mechanism*, e.g.:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.openmode = function(cmd) {
        cmd = cmd || 'on';

        switch (cmd) {

            case 'click':
                // read props, open windows, etc
                break;

            case 'on':
                this.addClass('openmode');
                break;

            case 'off':
                this.removeClass('openmode');
                break;
         }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

and then allow the plugin user to register the event handler which *triggers* that mechanism, using event delegation if necessary:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.openmode', function() {
    $(this).openmode('click');
});
```

The latter code could be put into the jQuery namespace too, as a utility function:

```
(function($) {
    $.openmode = function(cmd) {
        cmd = cmd || 'on';

        switch (cmd) {

            case 'on':
                $(document).on('click.openmode', 'a.openmode', function() {
                    $(this).openmode('click');
                });
                break;

            case 'off':
                $(document).off('click.openmode', 'a.openmode');
                break;
        }
     };
})(jQuery);
```

Such that just calling:

```
$.openmode();
```

will do all the work required to enable the plugin for every current (and future) `.openmode` element.

Comment: interesting approach. I'll give it a try

Comment: This is a nice solution IMO

Comment: For future readers, I update my jsFiddle to match your advise : http://jsfiddle.net/stevebeauge/7cqXC/14/.

Comment: To remain consistent, and keeping chaining, should the body of the method include a `return this;` ?

Comment: yes, the `$.fn` method should return `this`.  FWIW, none of this code is tested, either for syntax or functionality - it's just there to show an alternate (and IMHO preferable) structure.

Comment: here we can use this plugin only with a.openmode selector. we can not use this plugin for different kinds of elements like a.asdf means anchor tag with asdf class. right?

Comment: @zps215 the base plugin could be applied to any class - the final bit of code is just an example of how to make it apply to all elements with a specific class.

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to answer, but hope it helps someone. I had the same problem.

```
$.fn.plugin = function(){
  //some code
}
$(".element").plugin();            //works fine
$(".elementParent").append(".newElement");
$(".newElement").plugin();         // doesn´t work
```

It doesn't work because you need to call the plugin again after you added the element, like this

```
function runPlugin(){
   $.fn.plugin = function(){
      //some code
   }
}
runPlugin();                     //call plugin here
$(".element").plugin();          //works fine
$(".elementParent").append(".newElement");

runPlugin();                     // call plugin here
$(".newElement").plugin();       // works fine
```

Comment: I've run into this issue. From your code, does it mean you added a new function 'runPlugin' to the plugin's JS file? I tried it and then when I call runPlugin(); as you have done, I get the error - runPlugin is not defined.

Comment: That’s right. Think of the function wrapper Asi a variable. Every time you invoke it, you are invoking the whole script it contains. In regards to your issue, I’m not really sure if it works when using an external ja file for the plugin. However, you could try a) copying the file in your document or b) adding $(document).append(“<script src=[the url to your plugin]></script>”) before invoking the plugin

Comment: However, if I were to choose, I would choose the first option, as it is more efficient and doesn’t require loading up external files, making the script faster and more reliable

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it

Comment: So it seems there is no way to call the plugin on a class eg: `$(".my_class").somePlugin()`, and then, after a div with the class `my_plugin` is dynamically added, have that plugin automatically be applied to that new instance of `my_plugin`?  Isn't calling `runPlugin()` essentially the same as calling `$(".my_class").somePlugin()` again after the dynamic content is loaded?  When I have done this in the past, I always wonder if duplicate variables are being created when I do this, or do the plugins "overwrite" their existing instances?

Comment: In this case, the only thing runPlugin does is iníciate the plugin as by default it is iniciares onLoad (before any new elements are added). Doing so won’t duplicate the plugin as it only tells the script where the instructions are located

Answer (score 1):

I found a [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/stevebeauge/7cqXC/4/) that rely on the `on()` method, within the plugin.

The plugin is in this case waiting a `selector` argument to still keep the selector at the application level (not the plugin level) :

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myOpenMode = function (selector) {
        return $(document).on("mousedown", selector ,function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            var mode = $this.data("openmode");
            var href = this.href;
            var handled = true;
            if (mode) {
                switch (mode) {
                    case "NewWindow":
                        alert("NewWindow");
                        break;
                    case "Dialog":
                        alert("Dialog");
                        break;   
                    default:
                        handled = false;
                }
            } else {
                handled = false;
            }
            return !handled;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Then, I have to change the call to my plugin like this:

```
$(function(){
    $.fn.myOpenMode(".openmode");
});
```

This *is* working as expected. However, I'm not very confident in respecting jQuery plugin guidelines.

So if anyone has a better solution, I'll be happy to know.

Comment: you should never call a `$.fn` function directly like this.  `$.fn` functions are properties of jQuery collections, not standalone functions (which should be in `$`)

Answer (score 1):

You could still implement your own observer method, here extending append method:

```
;(function ($) {
    var fctsToObserve = {
        append: [$.fn.append, 'self']
    }, fctsObserveKeys = '';
    $.each(fctsToObserve, function (key, element) {
        fctsObserveKeys += "hasChanged." + key + " ";
    });
    var oOn = $.fn.on;
    $.fn.on = function () {
        if (arguments[0].indexOf('hasChanged') != -1) arguments[0] += " " + fctsObserveKeys;
        return oOn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    $.fn.hasChanged = function (types, data, fn) {
        return this.on(fctsObserveKeys, types, null, data, fn);
    };
    $.extend($, {
        observeMethods: function (namespace) {
            var namespace = namespace ? "." + namespace : "";
            var _len = $.fn.length;
            delete $.fn.length;
            $.each(fctsToObserve, function (key) {
                var _pre = this;
                $.fn[key] = function () { 
                    var target = _pre[1] === 'self' ? this : this.parent(),
                        ret = _pre[0].apply(this, arguments);
                    target.trigger("hasChanged." + key + namespace, arguments);
                    return ret;
                };
            });
            $.fn.length = _len;
        }
    });
    $.observeMethods()
})(jQuery);
```

Should works in old browsers too, but ya, observers got some performance issue, even you could optimize it.

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7cqXC/9/)

Comment: IMHO there's no need for an observer method.  The OP's plugin only ever does anything _useful_ in response to a user event, and jQuery already has a perfectly good mechanism for handling events on newly added DOM nodes.

Comment: @Alnitak   Im completly agree

Answer (score 0):

You can use the so called Mutation Observer approach to react to changes in your DOM. Here's more info about it:

[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/MutationObserver)

and here are some good examples:

[DOM manipulations](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)

Comment: I did not specify it initially, but I have to target IE8 and later. according the link you provided, this is not (yet) supported.