# A good method for passing 2 selectors into my jquery plugin for use with .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

Many jQuery plugins do something like this:

```
$('#selector').myPlugin({option:"value"});
```

However, inside myPlugin I want to use jQuery `.on()`, so I need another selector:

```
// my-plugin.js

(function($){

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {

        // Help!! I need a container here!
        $(?????).on("click", this.selector, function(){
              alert('success!');
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

**How do I pass another selector for use in the** `.on` **statement inside my plugin?** (I realize that a selector is only text and I could pass it with my options I'm passing, but is that the standard approach?)

**EDIT:**

Found this later and it also provides good clarification on dealing with this issue: [jQuery plugin to apply also on dynamically created elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542595/jquery-plugin-to-apply-also-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: `this.selector` is no longer supported... what are you trying to do... passing the selector as an option is the advised method now

Comment: I'm using version 1.11.0 and it's working for me?

Comment: inside anonymous functions, $(this) gets current object.. you can use jquery wrap to add a container to your $(this) if thats what you want.. so $(this).wrap("<div>") will wrap your caller element with a div. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes.... but it is deprecated

Comment: I want to make a call using `.on()` for delegation reasons. I can attach to a parent that is guaranteed to be there, so I need to receive another selector for this.

Comment: @ArunPJohny What alternative do you suggest, since `this.selector` is depreciated?

Comment: so you have a container? what's its ID?

Comment: @JFit Could be anything. Let's say I called it `#container`.

Comment: the suggested alternate is to pass the selector as an option

Comment: So there's not a way to get the selector from `this`??? That's ok, but how to accomplish my goal using just the elements directly?

Comment: Don't use the elements directly. It's pointless to select elements and then do nothing with them. This was one of the reasons (though there were several others) `.live` was so inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously have no need for the selected element, therefore i suggest instead creating your plugin on `$` directly rather than `$.fn` so that you don't waste time selecting elements that you'll never use. Pass in the context and selector through the options object parameter as an object.

```
$.myPlugin = function (options) {
    $(options.context).on("click", options.selector, function(){
        alert("Hello World!");
    });
}
$.myPlugin({
    context: "#container",
    selector: ".targetel"
});
```

An alternative would be:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function (selector) {
    return this.on("click", selector, function(){
        alert("Hello World!");
    });
}
$("#container").myPlugin(".targetel");
```

Comment: I'm mainly curious how folks normally attach their plugins to elements that are created later. By your example, you are suggesting I just need to expect 2 arguments to cover for this? What about an alternative that receives an element in a way I can delegate to it (other than simply referring to document)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You can pass whatever you want as a context or a selector. With it written in this way, it doesn't care if it's a string, jquery object, or dom node. The only requirement is that `selector` is a string. Anything other than a string doesn't make sense.

Comment: Because what you are suggesting is all those plugins I see everywhere could just be rewritten to receive the selector text?

Comment: Correct. Give me one example of a plugin that uses event delegation. One that comes to mind is the jQuery UI Tooltip plugin. If you want the jQuery UI tooltip plugin to use delegation, you have to use $(document).tooltip() and pass the selector that you want to use as an option(unless you use the default).

Comment: What's a good case for passing the element (instead of the selector) into a plugin? Almost about to accept your answer Kevin, for it's good insight.

Comment: I added a second example that covers the jQuery UI tooltip example, does that show a good case? `"#container"` can be anything that is valid in that location, for example `$(document)`, `$("#container")` or even `$(document.createElement("div"))`

Comment: The primary thing i'm suggesting is Don't do anything that would result in selecting elements and then throwing them away.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of would be the only answer. Like I mention in my question `...but is that the standard approach`. But I want to accept your answer for it's good insight!

Comment: Another thought to add to all of this...if no target is passed, I could assume the container is the target.

Comment: Correct, at which point you would just omit the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (edit)

```
(function($){

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
 settings = {
    container : null

    };
var options = $.extend({}, settings, options);
        // Help!! I need another selector here!
       return $(options.container).on("click", function(){
              alert('success!');
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

$('html').myPlugin({container:"body"})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/vpu33/

Comment: yeah, I knew I could do it this way...I was just wondering if there was another way to get the selectors passed, or get to the element delegated (because that's what I'm using `on()` for)

Comment: @DavidGraham Just sharing a possible option. see jsfiddle. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, definitely, this helped to reassure me others are attacking the problem in similar ways. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

hi see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/4cNRC/

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {


    $("#container").on("click", '#'+$(this).attr('id'), function(){
          alert('success!');
    });

    //OR if container is dynamic.. 

    $(this).parent().on("click", '#'+$(this).attr('id'), function(){
          alert('Dynamic success!');
    });

};
$('#someDiv').myPlugin({option:"value"});
```

Comment: What if it doesn't have an id?

Comment: updated.. @KevinB (in his example the id is #selector)