# jquery plugin on click doesn't work on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Am trying to create a simple jquery plugin for my web page the problem am facing here here is handling the click even for dynamic content.
I have tried using `document on click selector` but it doesn't work and but using `select on click` works fine when page load but on dynamic content it doesn't. When i use `$(document).on("click", clickedElement, function(event)` for the click event consoling `$(this).data("object-id")` will show undefined.

```
<span class="openModalTemplate" data-object-id="item100">Open 1</span>
<span class="openModalTemplate" data-object-id="item101">Open 2</span>
<span class="openModalTemplate" data-object-id="item103">Open 3</span>

<script>
$(function(){
  $(".openModalTemplate").Template({
    element: "#newOpen"
    type: "product"
  });
});
</script>
```

**My function**

```
(function($){
    $.fn.Template = function(options) {
        var clickedElement = $(this);
        if(typeof options === "object") {
             options  = $.extend(true, options, {
                 /*Locals*/
                element: '#createObjectElement',
                type: "product",
                action: null,
                apiURL: null,
                object: null,
                categoryType: "ITEM"
            });
        }


        $(document).on("click", clickedElement, function(event){
        //clickedElement.on("click", function(event){
            var currentElemnt = $(this);
            var action_id = $(this).data("object-id");
            //if(action_id  === undefined){action_id = options.action;}

            if(options.type =="close"){

            }
            console.log("action_id", action_id);
            console.log("element", options.element);

            if (options.onAfterOpen !== undefined) {
                 options.onAfterOpen(event);
             }
             if (options.onAfterClose !== undefined) {
                 options.onAfterClose(event);
             }
             if (options.onError !== undefined) {
                 options.onError(event);
             }
             event.preventDefault();
        });

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: unfortunately *from searching* there is no way to do this from inside the plugin .. the plugin set for the present elements not the new one .. so you need to run the plugin again for the new created elements  .. you can take a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542595/jquery-plugin-to-apply-also-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea and it worked

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef the problem is sometime it do execute the pligin function multiple time

Comment: as I said Peter *run the plugin again for the **new element*** .. add a new class to the new elements and run the plugin for this class

Comment: I updated my answer with the solution .. check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- unfortunately from searching there is no way to do this from inside the plugin .. the plugin set for the present elements not the new one .. so you need to run the plugin again for the new created elements
- And when you refresh the plugin the events fires multiple times and to avoid that You can add class to the elements then remove the class inside the plugin ..

see changes below

```js
(function($){
    $.fn.Template = function(settings) {  //<<< here
        var clickedElement = $(this);
        clickedElement.removeClass('ToPlugin'); //<<<< remove ToPlugin class
        if(typeof settings === "object") {  //<<<<<< here
             var options  = $.extend({
                 /*Locals*/
                element: '#createObjectElement',
                type: "product",
                action: null,
                apiURL: null,
                object: null,
                categoryType: "ITEM"
            } , settings); //<<<<< here
        }


        
        clickedElement.on("click", function(event){
            var currentElemnt = $(this);
            var action_id = $(this).data("object-id");
            //if(action_id  === undefined){action_id = options.action;}

            if(options.type =="close"){

            }
            console.log("action_id", action_id);
            console.log("element", options.element);

            if (options.onAfterOpen !== undefined) {
                 options.onAfterOpen(event);
             }
             if (options.onAfterClose !== undefined) {
                 options.onAfterClose(event);
             }
             if (options.onError !== undefined) {
                 options.onError(event);
             }
             event.preventDefault();
        });

    };
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add Span</button>
<span class="openModalTemplate ToPlugin" data-object-id="item100">Open 1</span>
<span class="openModalTemplate ToPlugin" data-object-id="item101">Open 2</span>
<span class="openModalTemplate ToPlugin" data-object-id="item103">Open 3</span>

<script>
$(function(){
  
  refresh_Template();  // use the function onload
  var i = 4;
  $('button').on('click' , function(){
    $('body').append('<span class="openModalTemplate ToPlugin" data-object-id="item10'+i+'">Open '+i+'</span>');
    i++;
    refresh_Template();  // use the function on click
  });
});
// create a function to refresh the plugin instead of repeat it every time
function refresh_Template(){
   $(".openModalTemplate.ToPlugin").Template({
    element: "#newOpen",
    type: "product"
  });
}
</script>
```

**Note:** don't forget to add the class `ToPlugin` to any element you need to use the plugin with (both static and dynamic elements)

Comment: It doesn't work when i use ajax to load some element

Comment: Can you see that it doesn't work i added `setTimeout` to your answer and it didn't work anymore